# Laravel 5.4 wherebetween with carbon fails to return data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a user that registered 2 days ago, on the 3rd (created_at: 2017-03-03 10:48:53)

I want to get the registered user count for each day, in the last 7 days.
My attempt is to put the code below in a for and change the subday to the for value, but it fails, returns 0. Any tips?

```
$date = Carbon::today();
User::whereBetween('created_at',array($date->subDays(5)->startOfDay()->toDateString(),$date->subDays(1)->endOfDay()->toDateString()))->count()
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's the type of `created_at` field ?

Comment: @HassanAhmed laravels default, timestamp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your problem is in the use of `Carbon` package ,

you've subtracted 5 days from your object, then you subtracted new day from the same instance , which will return a date range as follows :

[since 5 days] TO [since 5 days plus one day]

which will literally will create a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `xyz` WHERE created_at BETWEEN 2017-02-28 AND 2017-02-27
```

and to solve this , you have to :-

1) reset your date with today method

the right way to do this as follows :

```
$date->today()->subDays(1)->toDateString();
```

2) create new `Carbon` instance using the new date initialization .

following the first way :

```
$date = Carbon::today();
User::whereBetween('created_at',array($date->subDays(5)->startOfDay()->toDateString(),$date->today()->subDays(1)->endOfDay()->toDateString()))->count();
```